# Angular, change opacity property when ng-show/hide is included

Tags: css, angularjs

when I include ng-show **display** property of css comes into effect but I want to change **opacity** property.
In the documentation of angular it is written defining your own custom css using important will override the effect but it is not working.

```
<p ng-show="registrationForm.firstname.$invalid" class="help-block colorred">Enter only alphabets</p>
 <style>
 .help-block.ng-show{ opacity:1 !important;}
 .help-block.ng-hide{opacity:0 !important;}
```

I am new to angular.js.

Any kind of link or suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that the animations are applied to the state of either `ng-show` or `ng-hide`, e.g. whether an element with `ng-hide` is currently hidden (resolves to true) or not (resolves to false), the same for an element with `ng-show`.

So, for an element with `ng-hide`, change your CSS to:

```
.help-block.ng-hide-add, .help-block.ng-hide-remove {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  -o-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
  display:block!important;
}

.help-block.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.help-block.ng-hide-remove {
  opacity:0;
}

.help-block.ng-hide-add,
.help-block.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: This is not working. The default style of angular is not getting overridden.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; ng-hide push a display none. It is possible to put a display on the css class ng-hide.

```
.help-block.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
    display:block !important;
}
```

About !important, there is in documentation :

> By using !important, the show and hide behavior will work as expected despite any clash between CSS selector specificity.